# Regex to identify German, Chinese and Japanese

Tags: regex

I want to identify whether text is in Chinese, Japanese or German, using Regular Expressions.

For example I have some text like this "MainWindow_Button_save".
Its German translation is "MainWindow_Button_sparen".
Its Chinese translation is "MainWindow_Button_保存".
And Japanese is "MainWindow_Button_保存".

I want a regular expression which finds the prefix `"MainWindow_Button` and determines whether the following text is Chinese/Japanese/German. I'm not very much concerned about the text. The only thing I am concerned about is which of the three languages it is in.

What I have done is just this `"^MainWindow_Button_[^a-zA-Z]*"`, but how do I identify the language?

Comment: The bad news is regex doesn't have enough power to always detect between Chinese and Japanese for very short text, as your example has clearly showed. Though it is possible to pick out most of the cases if you detect for Hiragana and Katakana, which is only present in Japanese script. You can always differentiate between Latin script (German/English) versus CJK scripts though.

Comment: Which engine flavor?

Comment: Also, "save" is "speichern" in German, not "sparen" (which has the connotation of saving *money*, but not files).

Answer (score 0):

I tried working regular expression for the example [here](http://www.regexr.com/39jch)

I would suggest get the first and last character of chinese/japanese and put in regular expression "MainWindow_Button_(*[**保-存**]*)+", so that it matches to any chinese/japanese characters

If not using regular expression I would suggest in other way as follows in java:

Read the UNICODE value of the first character after "MainWindow_Button_", and verify whether the unicode value falls in chinese or japanese character set, if not in both then it will be german.

Comment: Yeah, actually I am using Squish Automation tool, and in that I can use regular expressions only.

Comment: @Nitesh Did you try RegEx with the above expression by including chinese characters in "[]" ?

Comment: It will work for me , So I am trying to search the complete range of chinese and japanese.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will help to provide the verification that the text is in either Chinese or Japanese:
^[\u3000-\u9FFF ]+$